# Objective-C Not able to download from Google?

Tags: objective-c, download, web-crawler

Ok so this won't just apply to just Google but in my case it does as I am trying to download content off of a Google search results that a user performs in my app but it's failing to work as such. I tried the same code on several other sites (bing, youtube etc) and it returned with the HTML content of the page requested, however, for google, it just logged out `null` at the `NSLog()` line and went on with executing the rest of the code:

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.google.ca/";
    NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSError *err = nil;

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

    NSLog(@"%@",html);
```

It appears to be an issue with memory? That Google's HTML is too much for the `NSString` data type? If so, what would I use to be able to access Google? Because I tried it on `http://www.google.ca/404` to see if it would download the 404 error, it did.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "skipped the NSLog" seems unlikely. Did it print nothing, or a datestamp an `(null)` or something like that. Why aren't you logging the `err`?

Comment: Also, you should really be using NSLog with a literal format string as that's how it's designed to be used.

Comment: @wain yes it skipped the NSLog completely, not even (null) and finished the execution of the next line of code `NSLog(@"done!")`

Comment: I'll try logging the error and get back, I am actually just experimenting with this code as I found it on SO and thought it would be a solution to my needs.

Comment: Change the log to `NSLog(@"%@", html);` and see if it's just the way you were logging.

Comment: when I log the error (`NSLog(err)`) It says this in the console: ` -[NSError length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100557310
`

Comment: You need to use a literal format string, you can't just pass any old object to NSLog...

Comment: @wain trying what you told me to, it is now returning `(null)`

Comment: *now returning (null)

Comment: @Wain, aside: NSLog won't output anything at all if the format string is `nil`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, good to know, I can't say I've ever tried it, thanks.

Comment: @wain what does the (null) signify?

Comment: `(null)` output from the NSLog means that (in this case) the `html` string is `nil`. Hence the NSLog was skipped (as per the comment from @JoshCaswell above). Did you log the error?

Comment: yes, I did log the error: -[NSError length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100513470

Comment: @Wain also is there any way to disable javascript when crawling using this method because I don't want the JavaScript code that brings the content, I want the plain text.

Comment: You get the `-[NSError length]:` because you aren't logging properly (should be `NSLog(@"%@", err);`)

Comment: @wain I am now getting: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)." UserInfo=0x101a111d0 {NSURL=http://google.com, NSStringEncoding=4}`

Comment: @wain I got it, to fix it, you need to change the encoding to ASCII which I did so and got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that UTF-8 encoding was the error. So to resolve this and still support UTF-8, I made sure it first tries UTF-8 encoding and if it returns an error, then it tries again with ASCII encoding like so:

```
 [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&err];
```

In this way you cycle through both UTF-8 and ASCII and the odds of an error are much less.

I hope this helps anyone else with this problem.